# Linux Pthread library, thread arguments

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

If I create thread using `Pthread` library under Linux, I need to use function `pthread_create`, as one of the arguments it takes `void *`, so I can pass a pointer to something, so my thread routine can get access to it, but is it safe to do something like this

```
{//some scope
    int a=5//scope variable
    pthread_create(&id,NULL,some_function,(void*)a);
}//end of scope
```

and in my routine:

```
void *some_function(void *_arg)
{
    int a=(int)arg;
    return NULL;
}
```

I want to do something like this, so I can keep the value of a variable on stack so I can access it from my thread routine but I don't want to create struct for single variable or manually allocate memory.

I will be creating few threads like this, so I wanted to know if in situation like this I can get by and don't use list or dynamic array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing is perfectly safe in the real world: conversion between `int` and `void *` is not undefined behavior, it's implementation-defined, and all implementations define it in the natural, sane way. It's also the only efficient way to pass single-integer arguments to a new thread. Other approaches all require expensive synchronization, either via explicit locking or by using `malloc` in the original thread and `free` in the new thread (which has implicit synchronization cost hidden in the `malloc`/`free` implementation).

One thing you will discover, however, is that some compilers issue warnings for the conversion. This is because of old broken code that assumes `int` can represent the full range of values of `void *`; the compiler is unable to distinguish between the (valid) practice of storing an `int` in a `void *`, and the (invalid) practice of storing a `void *` in an `int`. As a solution, you might want to use `intptr_t` instead of `int`, which will avoid the warning. If your original variables are `int`, simply adding an extra intermediate cast through `intptr_t` will avoid the warnings.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it is safe to push the value of `a` onto `some_function`'s stack via the *arg* argument because `void*`'s size is large enough to support the value of an integer.